# Fail to connect Camera service but I can get Camera informations

Tags: android, camera

I get a problem about Camera.open(). It throws an exception.

```
07-04 10:38:52.039  22582-22582/test.videorecorder E/Camera numbers:﹕ 2
07-04 10:38:52.049  22582-22582/test.videorecorder E/Camera 0﹕ 1
07-04 10:38:52.049  22582-22582/test.videorecorder E/Camera 1﹕ 0
07-04 10:38:52.559  22582-22582/test.videorecorder E/init camera﹕ can't open the back camera
java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
        at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
        at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:370)
        at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:329)
        at test.videorecorder.MainActivity.initCamera(MainActivity.java:72)
        at test.videorecorder.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:55)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:811)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:627)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-04 10:38:52.779  22582-22582/test.videorecorder E/preview holder﹕ surface create
07-04 10:38:52.779  22582-22582/test.videorecorder E/preview holder﹕ 1 times create
07-04 10:38:52.789  22582-22582/test.videorecorder E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: test.videorecorder, PID: 22582
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at test.videorecorder.MainActivity$2.surfaceCreated(MainActivity.java:115)
        at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:664)
        at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:93)
        at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:191)
        at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:847)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1888)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1017)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5603)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:811)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:627)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The code I write:

```
private void initCamera() {
    try {
        int defaultBackCamera = 0;
        Log.e("Camera numbers: " , "" + Camera.getNumberOfCameras());
        Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();

        for (int i = 0; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i ++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
            Log.e("Camera " + i, "" + info.facing);
            if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                defaultBackCamera = i;
        }
        mCamera = Camera.open(defaultBackCamera);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("init camera", "can't open the back camera", e);
        if (mCamera != null) {
             mCamera.release();;
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml I have added these lines:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

I looked many questions about opening the camera failed, but not one can solve my problem, so I want to know the reason and how to solve it.

Comment: There are only two documented reasons for the exception on `open()`: 1) no permission 2) camera already in use.  You have the needed permission in your manifest, so look for ways the camera could already be open.  Are you possibly calling `initCamera()` twice, and it works the first time and fails on the second?

Comment: No,it can't work first. My leader asked the engineers of the platform hardware and got the answer. They modified some programs and couldn't open camera by using general method. So, this question can't be solved unless they give us the right method.Thanks!